# installing rails on ubuntu permission denied

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, installation

After installing rubygems, I tried to install rails.

I entered the following command:

```
~$ gem install rails
```

and I got the following error:

```
Fetching: i18n-0.6.1.gem (100%)
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
    Permission denied - /var/lib/gems
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using `sudo` instead.

```
sudo gem install rails
```